# g++ and cilkscreen for detecting race condition

Tags: c++, g++, race-condition, cilk-plus

I'm trying to use `cilkscreen` to detect some race conditions in a code.
I'm compiling my code using

```
g++-5 -g foo.cpp -fcilkplus -std=c++14 -lcilkrts -ldl -O2
```

However, when I launch `cilkscreen` I get the following error message:

```
cilkview ./a.out

Cilkview: Generating scalability data
Cilkview Scalability Analyzer V2.0.0, Build 4421
1100189201
Error: No Cilk code found in program
```

Should I add some more option to `g++` ? Or does `cilkscreen` only works with code compiled with `icc` ?

FWIW: I'm using

```
gcc version 5.3.1 20160301 [gcc-5-branch revision 233849] (SUSE Linux)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cilkscreen/cilkview works only with icc/icpc.

Comment: How do you know ? Any reference for that ?

Comment: I released the latest version of Cilk tools, so my comment must be fairly accurate :). You can also check if the runtime library (libcilkrts.5.so) that comes with GCC contains a section named "itt_notify_tab". Cilk tools need to read that section to perform analysis.

Comment: Thanks for all the infos ! Sorry for my skepticism, but judging from your SO profile and reputation, I couldn't guess that you have such an expertise (I was also too lazy to google your name, again Sorry for that). Anyway, It's cool to have such skilled people following questions on SO. Tanks again.